# Update problem in Samsung J5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates

I have just re-installed Samsung J5 firmware manually. After install now whenever I try to check software update it gives error saying that " *Unable to update the software. A network or server error occurred. Try again later* ". I have tried many times, but same message appear. Before installing firmware was working fine. It gave me update of Marshmallow, but now gives error. Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: Id your device rooted?

Comment: No it is not rooted but i just installed firmware and it is due to install firmware.

Comment: Maybe there is a server error, possibly wait and try after few hours

Comment: I tried many times but still it gives same message.

Comment: If Marshmallow update for your device is available, then it should be available on SamMobile. Or even XDA. Suggest flash that directly (after checking you çhose the right one) using Odin, since your aim is to have Marshmallow

Comment: You are saying right,on SamMobile Marshmallow update is available.Here Question is if we somehow install Samsung firmware manually then is it really mean that in future we only have option to install it manually but not by auto check option,auto check option seems good you just busy in your work and get notification that there is an update available.Did it ever happened to other Samsung mobiles or just issue with J5?

Comment: If there is a future update for your device, which is very unlikely given Samsung policies, you may have both options, manually or auto but can't say for sure

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have installed Marshmallow firmware manually. Firmware was taken from www.sammobile.com site. Now auto update problem has fixed in Marshmallow. Now it does not give error. Sever network respond properly. Thanks to Sammobile web site.